# Are there any mobile app frameworks that are basically just a browser to connect to your mobile site?

Tags: android, ios, mobile

I have a client that has a very large and extensive mobile site and they would like to have a mobile app as well.  I know there are some services out there that will convert a mobile site into a mobile app but I have tried one in the past with poor results.  So basically as my question says, are there any frameworks or premade mobile app templates that will basically function like an app but connect to your live mobile site?

Comment: I heard of this framework called "Safari" that works well. It apparently comes pre-installed on all iPhones!

Comment: Don't know why I bother coming to SO -___-

Comment: It's just a comment; I didn't even vote to close or downvote this. Lighten up. :/

Answer (score 0):

Just make your own wrapped in a webview.

A previous client of mine stated with literally just that, a single activity with a webview. As he raised money for the app, I swapped portions of it out with native code. You can use a javascript bridge to handle some actions natively - share, etc.